# BaseDatabaseIntrospection in django

Tags: django, mongodb

I am creating a django project. while trying to implement mongodb, i upgraded my django framework. Now i keep getting the error message:

> NotImplementedError: subclasses of BaseDatabaseIntrospection may require a get_table_list() method.

Please kindly advice.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling mongo packages fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

Use [this](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/setup.html) link to install.

In short, do these steps:

1. remove mongodb for django by executing `pip uninstall django-mongodb-engine`
2. run `pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.5`

to install django non-relational stuff

3. run `pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox`

to install django toolbox

4. finally run `pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine` to install mongodb support for django.